# Trying to create a new column, get #1064 error

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I've been using phpMyAdmin to manage my db without any problem, but today I ran into this error if I try to add any column by using the interface to any table of any database:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `testing`  ADD `faaa` INT NOT NULL  AFTER ;
> ```
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

But if I add the column via SQL command in phpMyAdmin, this time by removing `AFTER`, the column is added without any problem.

I'm still inexperience with phpMyAdmin, so I guess I must have missed a mandatory field to fill when creating a new column in the interface. Can anyone shed a light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AFTER column_name` is used to designate which column in the table you want to insert the new column after.  You're providing the `AFTER` without telling it which column you want the new column to be inserted behind.  If you don't care about the order of the columns in your table, omit the `AFTER`, and the new column will be inserted at the end of the column list.

Comment: This is the right answer. As a follow-up, though, if PHPMyAdmin is telling you there's a syntax error, that's because MySQL is telling you there's a syntax error. Any time this comes up, there's something wrong with your syntax, not PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Oh geez, I get it and I am feeling so stupid now. But still, that is the SQL command that phpMyAdmin generates if I try to add a new column by clicking the "New" branch under the "Columns" tree.

Answer (score 1):

You have no column name after the `AFTER` statement, so the phpMyAdmin doesn't know where it should be put. Whether it's you forgetting to select the column or a phpMyAdmin bug, I have no idea because for adding a new column, the only required fields are the name and type, which you have.